# Using rename to change prefix of files recursively in Ubuntu, (regex not working)

Tags: regex, bash, ubuntu

I am using `rename` available in ubuntu:

```
$ rename --version
/usr/bin/rename using File::Rename version 0.20
```

This is what my directory looks like:

```
$ tree .
.
├── awp-3
├── bar
│   └── wp-2
└── wp-foo
    └── wp-1
```

My goal is that I want to rename all **files and folders** with the prefix `wp-` to `static-`

This is what I ran:

```
$ shopt -s globstar

$ rename -n 's/wp-/static-/' **
rename(awp-3, astatic-3)
rename(bar/wp-2, bar/static-2)
rename(wp-foo, static-foo)
rename(wp-foo/wp-1, static-foo/wp-1)
```

This is **almost** what I want. The file awp-3 should not have been renamed.

So I did this instead:

```
$ rename -n 's/^wp-/static-/' **
rename(wp-foo, static-foo)
rename(wp-foo/wp-1, static-foo/wp-1)
```

For some reason, this didn't change the filename of wp-1 or wp-2.

### How can i use rename to change wp-2, wp-foo and wp-1 to static-*?

Answer (score 0):

The `^` anchor only matches beginning of line.  I'm guessing you want

```
rename -n 's%(^|/)wp-%$1static-%' **
```

Another way to tighten this up is to say `wp` must only occur adjacent to a word boundary.

```
rename -n 's/\bwp-/static-/' **
```

Comment: I don't have access to this tool so can't test.

Comment: it should as easy as installing File::Rename from CPAN.

Comment: That's helpful; I could do that if I find the time to set up a separate virtual environment for testing this.

Answer (score 0):

Renaming files recursively using `rename` is problematic: you have to make sure that you rename the inner files/subdirectories first before renaming the parent directories. Simply adding the `/g` modifier to rename all the levels (e.g. `s!(^|/)wp-!$1static-!g` to rename(`wp-foo/wp-1`, `static-foo/static-1`) won't work.

It's better to use a tool that supports recursive operation, such as [perlmv](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlmv). I suggest a perl-based tool because rename is also a perl-based tool and they work similarly. Unfortunately there's not yet a Debian/Ubuntu package for perlmv, so you'll need to install it via a CPAN client (e.g. `cpanm -n App::perlmv`). Once you have `perlmv`:

```
% perlmv -R -de 's/^wp-/static-/' *
```

The result:

```
% tree .
.
├── awp-3
├── bar
│   └── static-2
└── static-foo
    └── static-1
```

Notes:

- you don't have to use `**` with perlmv, just `*`.
- `-R` is for recursive.
- dry-run mode in `perlmv` is `-d` not `-n`. Once you see that `perlmv` will do what you want, you can omit the `-d` or replace it with `-v` (verbose).
- you need to add `-e` before specifying perl code.